# Visualization data in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asp.net-core

I need to know how to visualize the backend data in the front end as a histogram or any other chart type. I'm using ASP.net Core as the backend and React as the front end.

Comment: There are tons of react charting libraries out there. Please describe the real question

Comment: I need to do a get request and get my data to a histogram I dont know about the libraries.Can you explain me about the libraries

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many ways to visualize raw data in a chart. If you want to use a ready made library then you could check out [chartjs.org](https://www.chartjs.org/)

Alternatively depending on the complexity of the chart that you want to create and whether you need to have a complete chart library, you could write your own code to display a histogram.

It depends on how comfortable you are with integrating / writing javascript / React code :)

Here's some values and a call to a simple React component that displays the data:

```
const distribution = [0, 1, 26, 92, 67, 67, 50, 32, 15, 19, 7, 7, 15, 9, 32]
<Canvas distrib = {distribution} />
```

Canvas.js

```
import React, { useRef, useEffect } from 'react';

const Canvas = props => {
  
  const canvasRef              = useRef(null)
  const distribution           = props.distrib
  const distFromLeftEdge       = 5
  const widthOfColumn          = 5    // Width (pixels) of Histogram column
  const distanceBetweenColumns = 16   // Distance between Histogram columns
  const chartHeight            = 190  // canvasHeight - chartHeight = Height of chart above the base
  const canvasHeight           = 200  // Total height of canvas
  const canvasWidth            = 400  // Total width of canvas

  const draw = ctx => {
    ctx.clearRect( 0, 0, ctx.canvas.width, ctx.canvas.height)
    ctx.fillStyle = '#999999'
    ctx.beginPath()
    distribution.forEach((el,index) => ctx.rect(distFromLeftEdge+distanceBetweenColumns*index, chartHeight, widthOfColumn, -1*distribution[index]))
    ctx.stroke()
    ctx.fillStyle = '#e6eef0'
    ctx.fill()
    ctx.height    = canvasHeight 
    ctx.width     = canvasWidth     
  }
  
  useEffect(() => {
    const canvas  = canvasRef.current
    const context = canvas.getContext('2d')
    draw(context)
  }, [draw])
  
  return (
  <>
    <canvas ref={canvasRef}  width={canvasWidth} height={canvasHeight} {...props}/>
  </>
  )
}

export default Canvas
```